# Will you provide a 'crayola' explanation of the OpenCL function atomic_inc?

Tags: opencl

If I had all of the information needed to answer this question I probably wouldn't need to ask it, but at least I have the creating company's specification link.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/atomic_inc.html

I've read quite a few definitions but am seeking a basic level explanation of what this function does.

Comment: What part of their definition you don't understand? Think of it as the postfix increment (x++)

Comment: FTFY: What part of their definition do you not understand? Although I appreciate a response, "postfix increment (x++)-  would never be considered 'crayola'.

Answer (score -2):

It atomically increments a 32 bit value and stores it in the same location in memory. You’d want to atomically increment if you have multiple threads reading and writing to the same location. This makes sure that only one thread will increment at a time.

[croninsiglos](https://www.reddit.com/user/croninsiglos/). Reddit. [ELI5: What does the OpenCl function atomic_inc do ?](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/he4ktk/eli5_what_does_the_opencl_function_atomic_inc_do/) asked by John Lutz on 22 Jun 2020.